# Compound pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

**Problem:**

> A compound pendulum is formed by suspending a heavy ring from a point on its circumference.  Determine the time period of oscillation of radius of the ring is $1\,\mathrm{m} .$

Given that a time period can be calculated using
$$
T =2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{I}{mgl}}
\,,$$
I took $I= \frac{1}{2}mR^2$ and $l=r ,$ which gave me an answer of $1.41 \, \mathrm{s} .$  But, the actual answer is $1.28 \, \mathrm{s} .$

**Question:**  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the rotation axis oriented? Can the ring rotate around an exis perpendicular to its plane, or around an axis laying in its plane? Knowing that the rotation axis goes through the point on a circumference is not enough.

Comment: Nothing about the axis is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The result depends on the orientation of the axis of rotation. It can be prallel to the axis of symmetry of the circle, tangent to the circle, or oriented in some other way, and this would give different results.

I'll assume the axis tangent to the circle, as it gives kinda closes result. The moment of inertia around this axis is $I = I_0 + mR^2 = \frac32 mR^2$ where $I_0$ s its moment of inertia around the axis passing through its center of symmetry  and lying in the plane of the circle, and additional $mR^2$ comes from shifting the axis away from the center of mass for a distance $R$.

Then you get $T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{I}{mgR}} = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{3R}{2g}} \approx 2.56 \text{ s}$.

Now, this is exacly twice the answer you were given. I don't know why you're given an answer being half of this, it may be a mistake in the book. By considering all possible choices of the axis it can actualy be proven that the the minimal value of the period of oscillations possible is $2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}R}{g}} \approx 2.39 \text{ }s $, which happens when the axis lies in the plane of the circle and passes in a distance ${R\over\sqrt{2}}$ from the center of the circle.